# Show notification after axios request is successful in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using **Vuex** to store some data. I have an action to login into my app. When the request is successful I want to display a notification ([iziToast](https://github.com/arthurvasconcelos/vue-izitoast) notification), but I don't know what it the best way to achieve that.

1.- Should I return a promise from Vuex and then handle the data from my Vue component?

2.- Can I use the library (**iziToast**) from Vuex? Or is this an anti pattern manner? How can I do this?

**This is my Vuex action:**

```
loginUser({ commit, state }, user) {
        axios.post("/api/v1/user/login", {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }).then(response => {    
        // Show notification here

        }).catch(error => {

        })
    }
```

Comment: I created my own "toast" type module with vuex and then called it after I receive a response.

Comment: and how do you open it? I mean, do you have to import the library to the module?

Comment: No, you call the dispatch method. This is what I do
dispatch('displaySnack', {message: 'Successfully added expense', color: 'success'}, {root: true});

Comment: Okay, but how can I use an external library like **iziToast**? How can I import it to the module and use it inside an **action**?

Comment: I've never used it before. Read the documentation, it should help you install it.

Comment: The library is working, what I don't know is how to use it from Vuex, it works well in components / vue files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212518/discussion-between-mikel-granero-and-savlon).

Comment: I'm in the discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Savlon said in the discussion, the `vue-izitoast` library was made for using it in components / vue instances, so the only way to make it work (in Vuex in my case) is to use the [**non-vue iziToast** version](https://izitoast.marcelodolza.com/) and import it as a normal npm library.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.- Should I return a promise from Vuex and then handle the data from my Vue component?

No, that's not how Vuex works.

Usually the flow would be something like this: 
The action gets started, which will trigger a Vuex mutation, which will update the store, causing a getter to update. Your component would have mapGetter setup for the value you're looking for and react to it.

Alternatively, you can skip using vuex altogether, in which case you could do this in the component, or a separate .js file. In this case you would return the axios call, since that is a promise.
like this: `return axios.post("/api/...`

> 2.- Can I use the library (iziToast) from Vuex? Or is this an anti pattern manner? How can I do this?

I'm not familiar with iziToast, but if there's no way to link it to a store or getter from vuex, you can likely connect them through any component, like a layout component.

for example, if you're using the vue-izitoast you could add this to any component

```
computed: {
  myMessage() {
    return this.$store.getters.myMessage
  }
}

watch:{
    myMessage(message) {
       if(message !== null){
         $toast.show( message, 'Note:', {position: "bottomLeft"})
       } else {
         this.$toast.destroy(); //not sure if it works, but I assume that might close open toasts
       }
    }
}
```

if your vuex has a `myMessage` getter

```js
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    myMessage: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setMessage(state, myMessage) {
      state.myMessage = myMessage;
    },
    clearMessage(state) {
      state.myMessage = null;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    myMessage: state => {
      return state.myMessage;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loginUser({ commit }, user) {
        axios.post("/api/v1/user/login", {
            email: user.email,
            password: user.password
        }).then(response => {    
          commit('setMessage', response.message)
        }).catch(error => {
          // could add a commit for error message here
        })
    },
    clearMessage({commit}) {
      commit('clearMessage')
    }
  }
});
```